# Remove last octet from the IP decimal form in R

Tags: r, ip

Is there any function that removes last octet of the IP in R libraries?
Or do I need to convert decimal ip to ip_V4 and then remove last octet by substring function?

Input: 973625971 (or 58.8.90.115)
Expected output: 58.8.90

Comment: Have you looked at the iptools package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iptools/vignettes/introduction_to_iptools.html. Maybe that will help. Your desired output is the string "58.8.90"? Or are you trying to identify an IP range?

Comment: Assuming it is the string '58.8.90.115',  `sub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", IP)`

Comment: I do not need range, just 58.8.90

Comment: I have not found any built function, to get this for the data.table of IPs.

Comment: `sub("\\.\\d+$","","58.8.90.115")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start from a numerical input :

```
library(magrittr)
a <- 973625971
a %/% 256 %>% (function (x) paste(x %/% 65536,x %% 65536 %/% 256, x %% 256, sep='.'))

#[1] "58.8.90"
```

If you want just a numerical output :

```
a %/% 256
#[1] 3803226
```

Comment: you can use `a %/% 256 %>% {paste(. %/% 65536,. %% 65536 %/% 256, . %% 256, sep='.')}` to make it a little less verbose.

Comment: please also include `library(magrittr)`